# $compiling Dynamic Components

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, components

I have a problem that I don’t know how to solve and hope someone can help…

I'm developing so application which need to render dynamic components, in order to do that I'm $compiling every component separately and caching it in order to avoiding recompiling and re-initialization of the controller of each component.

The problem is that when I'm adding a new component and using the cached $compiled component, the controllers seems to be gone and stops work.

I created a simplify of the sample in the following plunker...in order to demonstrate what I mean…adding component on going

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZN43Cwpi4RnJVf9Xy5K6?p=preview

This is the main directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive("dynamicComponents", function($compile, componentConfiguration) {
    return {
      scope: {
        components: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        var components = [];
        var renderComponents = function(scopeComponents) {
          for (let i = 0, len = scopeComponents.length; i < len; i++) {
            let componentItem = scopeComponents[i];

            if (!components[componentItem.id]) {
              let directiveHtml = '<' + componentItem.type.toLowerCase() + '></' + componentItem.type.toLowerCase() + '>';

              components[componentItem.id] = $compile(directiveHtml)(scope.$new());
            }

          }

          console.log(components);

          elem.html(components);
        }

        scope.$watch(
          function() {
            return componentConfiguration.getComponents();
          },
          function(newValue) {
            console.log("Rendering Tiles", newValue);

            renderComponents(newValue);
          },
          true);
      }
    }
  })
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not really clear what expected behavior is. Seems like whole thing could be simplified by giving each component an isolated scope and passing in each object

Comment: Also not clear why you are trying to do this caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it happens because you use `elem.html()` to replace the whole html of the directive, when some of it is compiled and some of it becomes static.

Anyway, if you replace the `elem.html()` with `elem.append()` in your example, it works.